# Bitwise differences in Java/Perl

Tags: java, perl, binary, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I was messing around and noticed differences that I don't understand between Java and Perl when I bit-shifted -1.

I thought integers are stored in two's complement binary, so if there are 32 bits, -1 is 11...11 (32 times).
I'd expect **-1 >> 1** to give $2^31 - 1$ = 011...11 = 2147483647.
I'd expect **-1 << 1** to give = 11...110 = -2.

What is the reason for these different behaviors and where are these standards stated in different languages?

Code and printouts for Perl & Java below:

In Perl:

```
print (-1 >> 1, "\n");
print (-1 << 1, "\n");
```

**2147483647**

**4294967294**

In Java:

```
public class Tempy {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println( -1 >> 1); 
        System.out.println( -1 << 1);
    }
}
```

**-1**

**-2**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Perl's bit shift is inherently unsigned so -1 is treated as 2^32 -1 and it automatically fills with 0 so `-1 >> 1` is 2^31-1 and `-1 << 1` is 2^32-2.

[Edit] Thanks @Powerlord using [`integer`](https://metacpan.org/pod/integer) will force perl to use signed values.

Java's bit shift sign extends (if using `>>`) so `-1 << 1` is still -1 and `-1 >> 1` is -2. If you don't want to sign extend you have to use the logical version `>>>`.

Comment: According to [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html), you can `use integer` to force Perl to use signed values instead.

Comment: (The signed integer -1 is 2^32 -1 or 2^64 -1 when treated as an unsigned integer, depending on your build of Perl. Specifically, depending on `perl -V:ivsize`)